# Is there a generally accepted name for the function $f = \{0 \text{ when } x=0, 1 \text{ when } x ≠0 \}$?

Tags: functions, terminology

In one of my computer programming projects I have defined the following quite common function:

$$
f(x) =
\begin{cases}
    0, & \text{ when } x = 0, \\
    1, & \text{ when } x \neq 0.
\end{cases}
$$

From what I understand, this is essentially an [indicator function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicator_function), more specifically $1_{x \neq 0}$. Unfortunately, most programming languages are quite restrictive in what one can use as an indentifier and mathematical symbols do not generally make the cut.

So, is there a standard *name* for this function? Something familiar to English-speaking$^1$ scientists that could be used in computer code$^2$?

$^1$ Yes, that means that something in, say, Sanskrit or Chinese would not be of much help.

$^2$ `functionThatReturnsZeroForZeroInputAndOneOtherwise` is not very helpful either...

Comment: Yes, Kronecker delta, or Characteristic function, or Indicator function, as you said.

Comment: actually, this would be one minus the Kronecker delta.

Comment: Indeed, $x\mapsto 1-\delta_{0,x}$. In the theory of Boolean algebras (with operators), this is called the *switching function* or *discriminator* (though it means some more general thing in universal algebra).

Comment: But, overall, I would call it simply *NonZero(x)*.

Comment: @Berci: to be honest I was hoping for a name that would not be confused with a function that returns a boolean value. Something along the lines of `nonZeroIndicator()` or something...

Answer (score 2):

You might call it `normalize ()` or `canonicalize ()`, since it normalizes/canonicalizes a representation in which `false` / $0$ is represented by $0$ and `true` / $1$ can be represented by any non-zero value to a representation in which each of them is represented by only one "canonical" value, which can then be used e.g. in equality comparisons.